# Bug in Unity 4.6 concerning canvases? (iPhone 5/iPhone 5s)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unity3d-gui

Stackoverflowish question: Is my issue here a bug, or can this be fixed somehow?

Bear with me now but I'm gonna post a couple of screenshots that will show how I think there's a weird bug that only (?) affects iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s.

- Confirmed affected: iPhone 5, iPhone 5s
- Confirmed not affected: Unity editor, iPhone 6 Plus
- Not tested: all other devices

Project zip: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/147970342/stackoverflow/testcanvasbuginunity.zip

Using Unity 4.6 release. (4.6.0f3)

This is the expected outcome when playing in Unity Editor.

[image: This is the expected outcome when playing in Unity Editor.]

This is the equally correct outcome (screenshot taken runtime with Xcode) when running on iPhone 6 Plus (no 5.5 inch launch image used).

[image: This is the equally correct outcome (screenshot taken runtime with Xcode) when running on iPhone 6 Plus (no 5.5 inch launch image used).]

This is the incorrect outcome (screenshot taken runtime with Xcode) on iPhone 5s/iPhone 5. Notice how the "canvaswithincanvasGame" is incorrectly positioned.
[image]

Now, this test app can be rotated to landscape mode and then back to portrait, if you do that this is the outcome. The "canvaswithincanvasGame" is now correctly positioned.
[image]

Now I'll just post the hierarchy and the setup of each canvas below for you to find the culprit, if any.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Some progress: Nesting canvases within canvases might be where the bug/problem is with Unity and iPhone 5/iPhone 5s. So a workaround is to not use canvases within another canvas. If I change the canvasWithincanvasGame to be a Panel instead the positioning suddenly works. Now in my game implementation I have a bunch of canvas within equivalent of canvasWithincanvasGame - these are still incorrectly placed. I'll go on changing them into Panel:s instead to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Good work on doing a bit of investigating but I would probably post this in the answers forum of unity3d

Comment: I used to for a week but I realised that there's no action in those forums when it comes to 2D development. Stackoverflow has been outpacing the official forums by far. Anyway I have reported this as a bug and moved on with other problems :-)